# Syntax error Invalid Property id in Extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I am trying to load the controller from Ext app.js
My code is

```
var controller = this.getController('member.Member');
```

Here Member.js is a controller inside my member folder under Extjs controller folder.

But I am getting error at the above line of code when loading controller.
Error is :

```
SyntaxError: invalid property id [Break On This Error]  

{

ext-debug.js (line 601, col 8)
```

Do anyone have idea whats this error is all about.

Comment: Are you sure when you are declaring 
var controller = this.getController('member.Member'); that "this" is the app ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error.
There is a syntax error of braces on my  controller.
Thanks to all.